# Как выровнять картинку по центру c другими элементами?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Мне нужно расположить строку поиска (картинку) по середине так, чтобы она не являлась блоком (т.е не переходила на следующую строку). В общем, как это выглядит сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как нужно чтобы выглядело:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="hat">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="logotype" alt="Aditu">

        <img src="images/search.png" class="search" alt="Search Panel">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: #39c8b0;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hat {
    background: #fff;
}

.container {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.hat .container .logotype {
    margin: 1.75% 2.14%;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/begprod/aditii

Comment: Почитайте про css flex

Answer (score 0):

Задайте для класса .container такие стили:

```css
.container {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вместо картинок поиска, карзины и других значков лучше использовать не картинки, а fontawesome.

Для выравнивания элементов лучше использовать flex-box.

Вот html-разметка:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
<form action=""><input type="text"><button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button></form>
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
</div>
```

Вот CSS-правила:

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  width:35%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


button{
  border:none;
  background-color: transparent;
 transform: translateX(-100%);
  cursor:pointer;  
  color:lightgray;
}
```